# На локальном сервере ошибки в JS, на боевом их нету

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть старый сайт, работает более года стабильно и без ошибок. Сейчас полез вносить изменения и обнаружил что на локальном сервере не работают js функции, и я получаю ошибки:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
- Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
- Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Перенес файлы с боевого сервера на локальный, но ошибки попрежнему остались, а на боевом их нету и все работает исправно.
Куда копать, что искать?
Ошибок которые пишет chrome в файлах нету...

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" — подключить jQuery ?)

Comment: На всяк посмотрите на какие файлы ссылаются сообщения об ошибках и визуально проверьте их после переноса. Иногда, при переносе, проектов по ftp через, например, filezilla, js файлы тупо бьются.

Comment: у вас с путями что то

Comment: Файлы не надо переносить filezilla никогда

Comment: походу файлы битые были, спасибо